# does konsole have a keyboard only block selection mode or is it broken

Tags: kde, konsole

I would like to select a group of words using the keyboard only.

https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/key-bindings.html

here they did have "Ctl-Shift-B"  to enter block selection mode, it does not seem to work.
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122831

termites contrl-shift-space does not work for konsole

alt + arrow keys will leap words, but with shift does not also select them

any help appreciated.

Comment: The bug report you provided reports itself as FIX RELEASED/RESOLVED (it's also very old),   However you've provided no details as to your OS & release which form a basis for looking up details, ie. your Qt version, Plasma release & software stack..

Answer (score 0):

Very good question, by the way, I also had this problem. What I was advised was:

When the "Show Log" menu option is selected, the window is going to minimize. Before the window minimizes, you have to check whether the user has selected any input to prevent the crash. You can check whether the user is selecting anything by using GetConsoleSelectionInfo.

The CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO out parameter should be equal to 0x00, and if it's not, you need to process the selection. As the documentation from GetConsoleMode/SetConsoleMode shows, you either need to call ReadFile or ReadConsole to discard the selection event that might be going on.

When you've implemented this, it shouldn't crash anymore.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply but I have no crashes, my question is only about block selection of text and the link I have was for that, not any bug.